# PHP Warning: failed to open stream: No such file or directory, File Path Errors

Tags: php, require

I am having trouble understanding how PHP chooses to compile or how including files within files works.

Here's my file structure:[image]

I require `secrets.php` inside `head.php`.
I require `head.php` inside `index.php`.

head.php

```
require "../environment/secrets.php";
```

index.php

```
require "php/head.php";
```

I get an error:

> Warning: require_once(../environment/secrets.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in /home/ubuntu/workspace/Cally
>   Dai/php/head.php on line 2 Call Stack: 0.0002 234760 1. {main}()
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/Cally Dai/index.php:0 0.0007 236632 2.
>   require_once('/home/ubuntu/workspace/Cally Dai/php/head.php')
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/Cally Dai/index.php:5 Fatal error:
>   require_once(): Failed opening required '../environment/secrets.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/Cally Dai/php/head.php on line 2 Call Stack:
>   0.0002 234760 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/Cally Dai/index.php:0 0.0007 236632 2. require_once('/home/ubuntu/workspace/Cally Dai/php/head.php') /home/ubuntu/workspace/Cally Dai/index.php:5

where am I going wrong?

Comment: This might be a longshot, but have you already tried setting the require "../environment/secrets.php"; relative to index.php? It's worth a shot.

require "environment/secrets.php";

Comment: @TimothyBomer That makes everything in the root directory work but other files, for example in the project folder, now start failing. It seems the file is being required relative to the file that is requesting the required file...but that shouldn't be the behavior correct?

Comment: Try changing:
require "../environment/secrets.php";

to

require (realpath(dirname(_\_FILE_\_)."/environment/secrets.php"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### When a PHP file includes another PHP file which itself includes yet another file — all being in separate directories — using relative paths to include them may raise a problem.

> PHP will often report that it is unable to find the third file, but
>   why? Well the answer lies in the fact that when including files in PHP
>   the interpreter tries to find the file in the current working
>   directory. In other words, if you run the script in a directory called
>   A and you include a script that is found in directory B, then the
>   relative path will be resolved relative to A when executing a script
>   found in directory B. So, if the script inside directory B includes
>   another file that is in a different directory, the path will still be
>   calculated relative to A not relative to B as you might expect. This
>   is a very important point to understand about the difference between
>   PHP and other languages like C/C++.

**One solution is to use `dirname(__FILE__)`:**

> Use `dirname(__FILE__)` – The `__FILE__` constant contains the full path
>   and filename of the script that it is used in. The function `dirname()`
>   removes the file name from the path, giving us the absolute path of
>   the directory the file is in regardless of which script included it.
>   Using this gives us the option of using relative paths just as we
>   would with any other language, like C/C++. We would prefix all our
>   relative path like this:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/dir/script_name.php");
```

Source: http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/

Comment: its equal to `include("./dir/script_name.php");`

Answer (score 1):

According to me, I feel that the path must be from root in ubuntu. Try your code with,
**require_once("/home/ubuntu/workspace/Cally Dai/php/head.php")**